# I can't access the bones

Tags: rigging

[image]
I'm want to animate this, but I can't access the bones, already turned on the "X-Ray"

This came from [this](https://www.blendswap.com/blends/view/26225) site. In the description says it was rigged.

[If you want to download the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uAccgqYL1qkdfoBdVfvEMJM0JEOwKVvf). (You have to create an account to the site in order to download it, so I upload it on Google Drive if you want to download it. The size is 2 MB.)

Answer (score 1):

The rig is on a layer you have hidden.  Layer nine. Right now you have X-ray on for the model; you may need to turn X-ray off of it before you will see the rig.

You need to have all layers you want to see visible. If you hold shift while selecting, you will be able to make multiple layers visible.

Comment: Thanks, I see the bones now. Problem is, if I go to layer 9 it only shows the bones (see [image](https://i.imgur.com/sNsEJkT.png) ). I want it to look like [this](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/cg/uploads/legacy/424_Blender_Rigging_LP_Characters/Preview.jpg)(mesh & bones shown)